# Excel Userform Input going haywire

Tags: vba, powerpoint, userform

I have the following code for a userform called **SlideSorterStart**:

```
Private Sub Okay1_Click()

Dim startOn As Integer
startOn = SlideSorterStart.Input1
Unload SlideSorterStart

End Sub
```

**Okay1** is the OK button here below, while **Input1** is the name of the text box.

[image]

I use the variable `startOn` in a module as follows:

Sub SlideSorter(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)

```
Dim first As Long: first = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex
Dim last As Long: last = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

SlideSorterStart.Show

For i = first To last

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(i)

        On Error Resume Next
        .Shapes("Squort").Delete

        Dim square As Shape
        Set square = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 400, 360, 150, 150)

        With square
            .Name = "Squort"

            With .TextFrame.TextRange
              .Text = startOn
           End With   ' TextFrame

        End With ' Square itself

    End With

    startOn = startOn + 1

Next i

End Sub
```

For some reason, instead of giving an output equal to the number filled into the UserForm, it always starts the first one at 0, and then the next time the function is run, increments by the number of slides.

For instance, if there are 5 slides to put this box on, then the first time, Slide 1 will have a 0. The next time at 5. Then a 10, and so on.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) strikes again!

You're showing the form's *default instance*, and inside that form's code, you're referring to the default instance of that form:

```
Dim startOn As Integer
startOn = SlideSorterStart.Input1
Unload SlideSorterStart
```

The `SlideSorterStart` identifier is dual-purposed here: it's the data type name of a `UserForm` class, *and* it's a project-scoped global object variable named after that form class.

You should NEVER refer to a form's *default instance* within that form's code-behind. Use the `Me` reserved identifier to refer to the *current instance* (could be the default one, but could be any other too).

```
startOn = Me.Input1
```

And whatever you do, NEVER `Unload` a form while that form is being shown and you need to later access its instance state (for example, the user-provided contents of a control).

Change your form's code behind as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Private StartAtSlideIndex As Long
Private HasCancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get StartSlideIndex() As Long
    StartSlideIndex = StartAtSlideIndex
End Property

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = HasCancelled
End Property

Private Sub Input1_Change()
    On Error Resume Next 'index will be 0 if can't convert text value
    StartAtSlideIndex = CLng(Input1.Text)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub Okay1_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
    HasCancelled = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that *nowhere* in the form's code-behind does the form get destroyed, or gets any opportunity to be destroyed: that's why we need to handle `QueryClose`, to prevent the form instance from being destroyed if the user cancels the dialog by clicking the red "X" button - and since the user is always free to cancel any dialog by doing that, the code that's showing the form needs to know whether the dialog was cancelled. If you decide to add a <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button, you only need to make its `Click` handle invoke the `OnCancel` method.

So, regardless of how the form gets closed, we only ever `Hide` it, and let the calling code destroy it.

```
SlideSorterStart.Show
```

That's showing the form's default instance. Avoid doing that.

```
With New SlideSorterStart '<~ form instance gets created here
    .Show
    If .IsCancelled Then Exit Sub

    Dim startOn As Long
    startOn = .StartSlideIndex
End With '<~ form instance gets destroyed here
```

The `Initialize` handler of the form, if present will be invoked at `New SlideSorterStart` (before the object reference is yielded to the `With` block); if present, the `Terminate` handler of the form will be invoked at `End With`.

Exactly when these two critical object lifecycle events are fired when you use the form's default instance, is non-deterministic: that's why you need to avoid it at all costs, and take full control of what objects you're using, and when and how you're destroying them.

The reason why you're getting `0` is because the form is systematically unloading itself; the default instance gets destroyed along with its state, and then it gets re-created again next time it's referenced, but then it's re-created with the default initial state, ...which means you effectively lose the user's input.

Comment: Read through your entire post on Rubberduck and the context-specific stuff you said in this answer. Incredible learning experience - I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Your `startOn` variable must be declared as Public at a module level.
It takes the value you set only for `Okay1_Click()` event.

You should also use `Option Explicit' in the module where`Sub SlideSorter' runs. In this way an error regarding the `startOn` variable not being declared will be raised.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! To clarify, are you saying I should have ```Public startOn As Integer``` above the ```SlideSorter``` sub? If so, this doesn't fix the error. /// I don't quite understand the second point you're making - I know it's about error handling, but don't get the implementation.

Comment: @TheveshTheva: @Mathieu Guidon explaind exactly what I meant. The `startOn` variable must be declared at a standard module level. I mean in such a module... If `SlideSorter' sub runs in a standard module, it should be OK. If it runs at a form level, it is not OK. If you do not have a standard module in your project, you must create one.

Comment: @FaneDuru except, that makes a global variable, and no global variables are *actually* needed (see other answer)