# vbModeless breaks UserForm

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following code in a module:

```
Public Sub AddInfoCreate(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)

With New MakeAddInfo '<- form instance gets created here
    .Show
    If .IsCancelled Then Exit Sub

    Dim MainName As String
    Dim AddName As String
    Dim AddNumber As Long
    MainName = .MainName
    AddName = .AddName
    AddNumber = .AddNumber
End With '<- form instance gets destroyed here

MsgBox "Let's solve this. " & MainName & ", " & AddName & ", " & AddNumber

End Sub
```

This module calls upon the **MakeAddInfo** UserForm, and is currently working absolutely fine.

If I change the `.Show` when I instantiate the form to `Show vbModeless`, the form no longer works. Specifically, it seems to be outputting the message box *before* I actually pull the input in.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? It's quite important for my user to be able to scroll while this UserForm is displayed.

Comment: I would just do it without using the `With` or the `New`

Comment: @braX I don't think this works - it breaks the functionality. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180858/4544928) shows why.

Comment: That's if you use a class... It's just not how i would do it.

Comment: Please split your 2 questions into 2 threads. 

As an alternative, have you tried setting ShowModal to False in the UserForm Properties? Any difference?

Comment: @JohnKorchok I've tried that - no difference.

Comment: Can we see the MakeAddInfo load sub too? something may be breaking it there.

Comment: @TheveshTheva Try calling `Show` at the bottom of the sub routine. Populating form fields after calling `Show vbModeless` may be what is causing this.

Comment: @rickmanalexander Don't think this help.